# Immutant2 server logs showing fishy error message

Tags: clojure, immutant, alipay

I got this error message a couple of times

```
21:36:01,172 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-18) Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ CONNECT www.alipay.com:443}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:121)
    at org.projectodd.wunderboss.wildfly.WildFlyWeb$1.handleRequest(WildFlyWeb.java:80)
    at io.undertow.server.session.SessionAttachmentHandler.handleRequest(SessionAttachmentHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

I believe Alipay is a chinese paymeny gateway. I am not using Alipay or any other payment gatweway currently. This is just a test application.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to use your site as a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel) tunnel. If you use a reverse proxy like nginx in front of your site, you can prevent requests like this from hitting your app.

Comment: I am already using a reverse proxy with nginx. Are you suggesting this is a hack attempt?

Comment: You should be blocking the CONNECT protocol with nginx, unless you intend to be offering an HTTP proxy. It's likely an attempt to mask their attack on Alipay using your IP.